# How to properly use plsr() in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am learning `plsr`in R and come across several different examples which make me confused. I have seen two ways of fitting and finding best number of components in the following two ways. I just want to know which of these is proper way and preferred one?

1) Lets say we have a dataframe called data and it is split into train data `data.train` and test data `data.test`. Then plsr is fitted as

```
plsr.fit = plsr(formula, data = data.train, validation = "CV", scale = TRUE)
summary(plsr.fit)
```

then getting `ncomp` value based on smallest `CV` value.

2) Without any split of data, simply fitting the model into full data

```
plsr(formula, data = data, validation = "CV", scale = TRUE)
summary(plsr.fit)
```

then getting `ncomp` value based on smallest `CV` value.

The part I get confused is the first method. Since `validation = "CV"` is already included and it does automatically apply 10-fold CV, why the model is fitted into training data, instead of full data? Isn't in this case train data again will be split into training and test data and 10-fold cross validation applied automatically?

Comment: Is `plsr` a function you've defined or does it come from a package?

Comment: No. it is built-in (partial least squares regression) function which is under `pls` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run cross validation, you're still fitting to the data set you're using. You can't really test the accuracy of your model unless you compare it to data it's never seen. That's why you usually split your data into roughly 80% for "training" (including cross-validation or whatever other method you choose) and 20% for "testing" *after* cross-validation.

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks @Matt